# Ventana top level se queda pasmada en TKinter de Python 2.7

Tags: mysql, python, python-2.7, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Necesito apoyo. En la aplicacion que estoy desarrollando puse un boton para que abra una ventana top level con los campos que tiene mi tabla **MySQL** y asi modificar algun registro ya creado, a su vez quiero que sobre esa top level aparezca un menu desplegable para seleccionar el elemento de la tabla a modificar pero a la hora de que presiono el boton **"Modificar"** la aplicacion se pasma y deja de responder. Por que podria estar pasando esto?. Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
from Tkinter import *
import MySQLdb
import os
import tkMessageBox
import csv

#ventana

ventana = Tk()
ventana.title("Erick Finn's Reporter")
ventana.configure(background = "brown")


def insertar():
      Id = int()
      d1 = fecha_text.get()
      d2 = usuario_text.get() 
      d3 = aplicacion_text.get() 
      d4 = folio_text.get() 
      d5 = status_text.get() 
      d6 = inputway_text.get()

  conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = "127.0.0.1", user = "root", passwd = "unitec", db = "efrias002")
  cursor = conn.cursor()

  sql ='INSERT INTO base17 VALUES("%s","%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s","%s")'%(Id, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6)

  try:
      cursor.execute(sql)
      conn.commit()
      conn.close()
      tkMessageBox.showinfo("Info","Registro Agregado Correctamente")

  except:
      conn.rollback()
      conn.close()


def mostrar():
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = "127.0.0.1", user = "root", passwd = "unitec", db = "efrias002")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM base17")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    for item in data:
    list1.insert(END,item)
    conn.close()

def buscar():
    res = busqueda_text.get()
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = "127.0.0.1", user = "root", passwd = "unitec", db = "efrias002")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM base17 WHERE usuario = %s",[res])
for item in cursor:
    list1.insert(END,item)
conn.close()

def buscar2():
     res2 = busqueda2_text.get()
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = "127.0.0.1", user = "root", passwd = "unitec", db = "efrias002")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM base17 WHERE fecha = %s",[res2])
for item in cursor:
    list1.insert(END,item)
conn.close()

 def generar():
  conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = "127.0.0.1", user = "root", passwd = "unitec", db = "efrias002")
  cursor = conn.cursor()
  cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM base17")
  rows = cursor.fetchall()
  fp = open('file.csv', 'w')
  myFile = csv.writer(fp)
  myFile.writerows(rows)
  fp.close()
  conn.close()

def win2 ():
  t1 = Toplevel(bg="Brown")
  t1.title("Modificar Datos")
  t1.geometry('600x400')
  t1.focus_set()
  t1.grab_set()
  t1.transient(master=ventana)

  inf=StringVar()
  t2=Entry(t1,textvariable=inf)
  t2.grid(row=3,column=1)

  inf2=StringVar()
  t3=Entry(t1,textvariable=inf2)
  t3.grid(row=3,column=3)

  inf3=StringVar()
  t4=Entry(t1,textvariable=inf3)
  t4.grid(row=3,column=5) 

  t2l = Label(t1,text='Fecha',bg="Cyan2")
  t2l.grid(row=0, column=1)

  t3l = Label(t1,text='Usuario',bg="Cyan2")
  t3l.grid(row=0, column=3)

  t4l = Label(t1,text='Aplicacion',bg="Cyan2")
  t4l.grid(row=0, column=5)

     #menu despleglable

  OptionList = ['Fecha','Usuario', 'Aplicacion']

  listin = StringVar()
  listin.set(OptionList[0])

  men = OptionMenu(t1,listin, *OptionList)
  men.pack()

def borrar():
    list1.delete(0,END)

def salir():
    ventana.destroy()


pic = PhotoImage(file = "pwc2.gif")
wid = Label(ventana,image = pic)
wid.pack()
wid.grid(row=2, column=11,rowspan=3)

l1=Label(ventana, fg= "Blue",bg="Orange",text = "Fecha")
l1.grid(row=0,column=2)

l2=Label(ventana,fg= "Blue",bg="Orange",text = "Usuario")
l2.grid(row=0,column=3)

l3=Label(ventana, fg="Blue",bg="Orange", text = "Aplicacion")
l3.grid(row=2,column=2)

l4=Label(ventana,fg = "Blue",bg="Orange",text = "Folio Ticket")
l4.grid(row=2,column=3)

l5=Label(ventana,fg="Blue", bg="Orange",text = "Status")
l5.grid(row=4,column=2)

l6=Label(ventana,fg = "Blue",bg="Orange", text = "Input Way")
l6.grid(row=4,column=3)

l7=Label(ventana,font = "Comic",bg="DeepSkyBlue" ,text = "Resultados")
l7.grid(row=29,column=2,columnspan=3)

l8=Label(ventana,fg = "Blue",bg="Orange",text = "Busqueda por usuario")
l8.grid(row=2,column=4)

l9=Label(ventana,fg = "Blue",bg="Orange", text = "Busqueda por fecha")
l9.grid(row=4,column=4)

#campos de entrada

fecha_text=StringVar()
e1=Entry(ventana,textvariable=fecha_text)
e1.grid(row=1,column=2)

usuario_text=StringVar()
e2=Entry(ventana,textvariable=usuario_text)
e2.grid(row=1,column=3)

aplicacion_text=StringVar()
e3=Entry(ventana,textvariable=aplicacion_text)
e3.grid(row=3,column=2)

folio_text=StringVar()
e4=Entry(ventana,textvariable=folio_text)
e4.grid(row=3,column=3)

status_text=StringVar()
e5=Entry(ventana,textvariable=status_text)
e5.grid(row=5,column=2)

inputway_text=StringVar()
e6=Entry(ventana,textvariable=inputway_text)
e6.grid(row=5,column=3)

busqueda_text=StringVar()
e7=Entry(ventana,textvariable=busqueda_text)
e7.grid(row=3,column=4)

busqueda2_text=StringVar()
e8=Entry(ventana,textvariable=busqueda2_text)
e8.grid(row=5,column=4)


#definir listbox

list1 = Listbox(ventana,bg = "white",height=15, width=90)
list1.grid(row=30, column=2, columnspan=4)


#crear scroll

sb1=Scrollbar(ventana)
sb1.grid(row=30,column=6)

list1.configure(yscrollcommand=sb1.set)
sb1.configure(command=list1.yview)


#crear botones

 b1=Button(ventana, text="Crear nuevo registro",bg = "Light Green",       command=insertar)
b1.pack()
b1.grid(row=24 ,column=11)

b2 = Button(ventana, text="Mostrar Registros",bg = "Orange",   command=mostrar)
b2.pack()
b2.grid(row=26, column=11)

b3 = Button(ventana, text="Buscar por Usuario",bg = "Yellow", command=buscar)
b3.pack()
b3.grid(row=27, column=11)

b4 = Button(ventana, text="Limpiar Consulta",bg = "Light Blue", command=borrar)
b4.pack()
b4.grid(row=29, column=11)

b5 = Button(ventana, text="Salir de la App",bg = "Red",fg="Yellow", command=salir)
b5.pack()
b5.grid(row=31, column=0)

b6 = Button(ventana, text="Crear CSV",bg = "Light Gray", command=generar)
b6.pack()
b6.grid(row=30, column=11)

b7 = Button(ventana, text="Buscar por Fecha",bg = "SeaGreen1", command=buscar2)
b7.pack()
b7.grid(row=28, column=11)

 b8 = Button(ventana,text="Modificar Datos",bg="Cyan2", command=win2)
 b8.pack()
 b8.grid(row=25,column=11)

 ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hola Erick, dos observaciones primero: tu código tiene múltiples errores de identación, data la importancia de esto en Python te sugiero que lo corrijas y que a poder ser uses siempre 4 espacios para tabular como recomienda PEP8 (las tab dan muchos problemas ya que en cada sistema pueden significar una cosa distinta). Por otro lado, llevas ya varias preguntas en el sitio, algunas con respuestas en las que comentaste que fueron de ayuda, te recomiendo que consideres aceptarlas, para saber como mírate: [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427/15089)

Comment: En cuanto a tu problema, la pregunta clave es ¿Cuantas filas te retorna la consulta? Ten en cuenta que tu función `mostrar` es bloqueante, esto impide que el mainloop encargado de dibujar la GUI y responder a eventos se bloquee y por tanto, si la función tarada en retornar demasiado la GUI se congela. Si hablamos de una decena de filas no habría mucho problema a no ser que el servidor tarde en responder por alguna causa, si hablamos de medio millón tienes un problema.

Comment: Hola FJ, gracias por tu comentario. Se hecho se me ocurrio intentar meter el menu desplegable dentro de un Frame y esto hizo que la app ya no se congelara. En cuanto a la identacion, fue mas por el tipo de edicion que te permite esta pagina osea lo de los 4 espacios.